# Problems downloading remotely from IP Camera using iVMS-4200 software

Tags: ubuntu, download, ivms

I have access on a few IP camera through [iVMS-4200](http://www.hikvision.com/en/us/download_more.asp?id=1296) software. I can live view them and also load remote playback for previous recordings. However, when I try to download a specific video, I have the following error:

> Status : Manually stop
>
> Error message: Insufficient HDD space, can't proceed

I tried to change the location of download on my laptop, but still have the same error.

I use Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and iVMS-4200. Is there any way to fix the problem or use another way to download the videos?

[image]

Comment: Do you have enough HDD space?

Comment: In my laptop? Yes. About 250Gb and the file is only 300mb...

Comment: A long shot based on [this thread](http://www.cam-it.org/index.php?topic=5891.0) : change the download folder to a disk/partition that does not contain the operating system.

Comment: @harrymc I am using Linux and the file path is on the personal folder and not on the computer root.

Comment: This is still just a long shot, but is the personal folder in a different *physical* disk/partition than root? Try even an external disk.

Comment: @harrymc ivms doesn't let me to choose anything else than the "computer" which is the root folder and the folder with my name, which is the direction with folders "pictures, downloads, documents" etc...I have another partition but it isn't in the options. Even if I put an external disk.

Comment: Are you sure about the wording of the above error message?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FPMoBlE.png The only thing I could imagine is that it tries to download it on server and not on my local laptop. Since, I have about 300GB free space and not 16GB as the screen shot says

Comment: Your local setup is not well-enough described. You need to add more info & screenshots to the post. You could try to change the download folder, and show us screenshots of what you are trying to, your disk-space and network.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, luckily managed to solve. 
You're running out of system memory (RAM). Try to restart your computer and run only the ivms application in order to save (RAM) memory space.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: @DavidPostill pretty fierce expectation for third party software that the OP has no hand in writing or maintaining

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem for me (I have more than 20GB of free RAM)