# Problems downloading video from camera iVMS-4200

Tags: download, camera, ip-camera, ivms

I see there is an [almost identical question](https://superuser.com/questions/892576/problems-downloading-remotely-from-ip-camera-using-ivms-4200-software) to this one, from 2 years ago and with no answers, so was hoping that people would have new ideas on how to solve it.

My computer is `Windows 10` running `iVMS-4200 V2.6.2.7`. It is connected directly into a switch. The camera is also connected directly into the switch. There is nothing else connected (no router/etc.). The camera has an internal 100GB SD card.

When I try to download a recording I get the error shown in the screen shot below: `Insufficient HDD Space` (bottom right). As you can also see from that screen shot, there 24.8GB available on my hard drive.

[image: Hikvision]

I am able to replay recordings no problem.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to solve it?

As a side note, what does the status of "Waiting" mean? All of my recordings have that status.

Comment: Waiting would be with regards to a download queue, waiting, for the download to finish

Comment: How large is your page file?  How much physical memory do you have?

Comment: @Ramhound Just looking in Task Manager... I've got 16gb of RAM and only 7 is actively being used.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. It's a bug in the Hikvision software that makes it not compatible with Windows 10.

The software is not able to get the available space correctly when trying to save the file on disk due to the fact they use a call from an older Windows DLL that is no longer compatible with Windows 10.

I tried all the obvious solutions:

- Making more space available
- Setting the directory where the files are saved to a different drive.
- Checking the write permissions

It is interesting that the GUI is using a different system call so is able to see that there is plenty of available space on the target drive, but the actual code that searches and extracts the video from the storage server is  using the old system call.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old question and maybe you already solved it, but I thought it would be usefull to share the solution, since one exists.
I had the same problem, and solved it installing the latest version of the software (3.3.1.8)